# Proper way to add an Echo Dot 2 to my existing system

Tags: amazon-echo

I have an Echo 2 paired with an Amazon Bluetooth receiver which in turn feeds an 70v Amp that plays throughout the home.  This works. However, my wife has to constantly go from the Kitchen to the Great Room to speak to "Alexa."

My solution was to put a Dot in the kitchen so she could control things from there. This Dot is also successfully paired with the same Amazon Bluetooth. I can control it from the kitchen.

The problem seems to be that it is an either/or control. If I start a music stream from the Dot, I cannot control it from the Echo 2, and vice verse. I added the two Echos to a "music group" and that worked but they played through their built-in speakers rather than the 70v home system.

Is what I am trying to do possible?  Am I just doing it incorrectly?  Would it work if I bought a 2nd BlueTooth receiver for the Dot?

UPDATE: 
I thought, perhaps only one of the units should be paired with the BT and the two units being in the same group (Everywhere) would "link" and the one paired with the BT would feed that line.  What happened was that the one that was paired with the BT disconnected, and the two units played through their internal speakers.

This is a frustrating puzzle that should not be this difficult to accomplish.

Comment: If I understand correctly I think only the whole house system belongs in the “group” (meaning the “group” only has a single member).  The cumbersome part is always having to name the group in your Alexa command “play ____ on group”.   You can’t tell Alexa to play on a different device, but you can tell her to play on a group.

Comment: Tyson, I'm confused. I thought I had to "link" the Echo 2 and the Dot by putting them in the group.  If only one (Let's say the Echo 2) is in the group, how do I control channel, volume, etc, through the Dot?

Comment: “Alexa, play ____ on, (name of group name)”, or actually I just tried “Alexa play ___ on (name of different echo device)” what you play ‘on’ is where the music comes out.  I don’t think you can change volume on a different device tho.  The only group actually have is ‘everywhere’ which plays same audio on all devices.  So I’m not sure it works the way you want it to.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait ... you're saying my Dot does not have to be in the group to send commands TO the group?  This is a new twist I'd never even considered. I'll give it a try, but conceptually it makes sense.

Comment: Confirmed, Tyson. I can instruct Alexa to play "on Great Room" but I cannot control anything once that is playing.  There HAS to be a way to do this. These darned devices are so "smart" that this seems to be a huge oversight.

Comment: UPDATE: Tyson, you nailed it!!  If I am in the kitchen, I can indeed say, "Alexa, Volume up ON GREAT ROOM" and it works!!  She sends that command from Kitchen Dot to Great Room and the volume goes up and down.